# UICollectionReusableView constraints not updating

Tags: ios, autolayout

I'm trying to dynamically activate/deactivate some layout constraints on my `UICollectionReusableView` subclass upon some loading event.

I've got my layout constraints set up, some are activated and some are deactivated. (before you ask, **all my constraints are strongly referenced, I know that deactivated constraints aren't held and are deallocated**)

Upon a refresh code, I activate some constraints/deactivate others (and in debugger, make sure none of them are somehow `nil`), call `setNeedsLayout` and `layoutIfNeeded` on the cell, but nothing happens. I inspect the layout visually and check the constraints. The constraints are as if my code hasn't even been hit (of course, it is hit, I've put a debugger). No constraints are broken either, I've checked the logs. A constraint that I've deactivated is still active, and a constraint I've activated is not activated, and the visual layout confirms this state.

I've also logged some text from `awakeFromNib` and it's only logged once, so there's not an another instance of the header.

What might be the reason that constraints are not activated/deactivated even though the code is hit and everything is referenced correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, turns out the problem was related to the header view being manually held by the owner view controller as an instance variable and not dequeued/reused after once it's dequeued initially (`viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:atIndexPath` always returned that instance variable thereafter). There wasn't any problem with my constraints.

The previous developer, for some reason held onto a strong reference of the view manually and always returned the same view, it probably caused some internal instability in collection view's behavior. I've corrected it to the regular `dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:withReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath` way of returning the header cell, and the problem went away.

Never hold onto a reference of the reusable views/cells (or at least, don't forget to call dequeue code whenever required and refresh the pointer). Seems that it causes undocumented/unpredictable layout issues.